# How to jump from function name to function params in VS Code - Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have maybe a stupid question but how can I jump from function name to function params in VS Code. I want a keyboard shortcut.
When I write a **fc** and I press a tab I will get this:

```
function name(params) {
}
```

and I can rewrite name instantly. How can I jump to the **params** and have selected the whole word for rewriting?

Thanks

Comment: Just hit tab after you rewrite the function name - it will skip to the params with that word selected.  Hitting tab after that takes you to the function body automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using a snippet that creates a function. After you have typed the name, you should then press the `TAB` key, this will let you edit the parameter.

In this animated gif, after I write the function name "qux", I press the tab key, and then type the parameter name "bar":

[image: showing how to tab between name and tab]

Comment: I need help understanding the downvote. How does this not answer the question?

Comment: the downvote was not from me. I had upvoted this and i had accepted answer.